# Make QtCreator to show results of a 3dParty tool into its issues pane instead of compile pane

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using a code analysis tool with QtCreator. The results of the tool are presented in compile pane of the QtCreator as expected. How can I make QtCreator to show the results to its issues pane?

[This address](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-task-lists.html) give some insights but very ambiguous.

Thanks in advance...